# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionContext

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-5.x

I am developing `Spring MVC Hibernate` Integration example. In this example I'm using `Spring 4.1.9.RELEASE` and `Hibernate 5.1.0.Final`. If I downgrade Hibernate version to `4.3.5.Final` then it works. Now inorder to use hibernate 5 what else configuration do I need to change. Please refer more details below.

Please find below the exception I see

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionContext
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.isSameConnectionForEntireSession(HibernateTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:445)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:463)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.listPersons(Unknown Source)
    at com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.listPersons(PersonController.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:856)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:841)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The configuration which I used are:

```
<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <!-- DataSource -->
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <!-- Annotated Class -->
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>

        <!-- Hibernate Properties -->
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

And other configurations are:

```
<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
```

It looks to me that this package `org.springframework.orm.` don't have configurations for the `hibernate 5` yet, please guide what configurations I need to change in order to use `hibernate 5`?

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.1.9.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Entity Manager-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOG4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Change the definition of your transaction manager to:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

And upgrade your spring framework to 4.2.x

Comment: It look like this is the right answer but can you translate* it to @annotation mode, Your answer well be more perfect and usefull... and thanks.

Comment: Didn't you have to change `hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory` to hibernate5 ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following setup as well for Spring 4 + Hibernate 5:

spring setup:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

pom.xml setup:

```
<properties>
  <java-version>1.7</java-version>
  <org.springframework-version>4.3.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
</properties>

<!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- Hibernate -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Tried and tested.

Comment: same remark, can you translate* it to @annotation mode, Your answer well be more perfect and usefull... and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your `pom.xml` you have `Hibernate 5`,try to pass from `hibernate5` to `hibernate4`) in your pom:

```
  <hibernate.version>4xxxx</hibernate.version>
  ...
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You missed my above comment, I can't simply use hibernate5 instead of hibernate4, it gives me Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Class 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager' not found [config set: SpringMVCHibernate/web-
  context]
 - Class 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager' not found

Comment: Okay use hibernate4  in you pom.xmlversion to <hibernate.version>4.xxxx</hibernate.version>

Answer (score 1):

Changing the below import from hibernate4 to hibernate5 in hibenate configuaration file  worked for me,

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
```

to this

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create an application context that works well for both Hibernate 4 and Hibernate 5 at the same time.<sup>[why?]</sup>

So I replaced Hibernate-specific transaction manager (`org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager`) with Spring JPA transaction manager (`org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager`):

```
// part of my Java Config
@Bean
@Autowired
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, DataSource mainDataSource) {
    final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    transactionManager.setDataSource(mainDataSource);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

<sup>[why?]</sup> Because this context is shared between different modules that depend on different Spring and Hibernate versions.

Comment: I had all my configuration based in `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager` but when I upgrade my project to `spring boot 1.5.14.RELEASE` there is an error going: 

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor` and all my RestRepositories for example are not working anymore

Do you know any solution for this?

Comment: @DanielHenao it's hard to tell without looking at your actual code. Take a look at the similar questions: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41228333/1429387), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464428/1429387).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. I have removed this part my config class and it's solved.

```
@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
```