# Spring Boot - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionContext

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I am new on Spring Boot. I am trying make a web app using Hibernate but I am experiencing these errors. I looked similar questions but I couldn't find a solution. How can I solve it?

> 2016-12-19 18:56:39.328  INFO 143744 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core
>   {5.0.11.Final}
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionContext   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_91]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_91]    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.isSameConnectionForEntireSession(HibernateTransactionManager.java:711)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:445)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.listPosts(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]     at
>   com.monat.service.PostServiceImpl.listPosts(PostServiceImpl.java:24)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.monat.controller.PostController.list(PostController.java:20)
>   ~[classes/:na]

My pom.xml dependencies

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

My Controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostController 
{

    @Autowired
    PostService postService;

    @RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("listData",postService.listPosts());

        return "list";
    }

}
```

My Service Class

```
@Service
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService{

    @Autowired
    PostDao postDao;

    @Override
    public List<Post> listPosts() {
        return postDao.listPosts();
    }

}
```

My Repository Class

```
@Repository
public class PostDaoImpl implements PostDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public PostDaoImpl(){}

    public PostDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory=sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Post> listPosts() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Post> listPost2 = (List<Post>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Post");

        return listPost2;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved it. I have removed this part my config class and it's solved.

```
  @Bean
  public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = 
        new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these dependencies to the **dependencies** section of your pom and rebuilding your project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually with spring boot and hibernate you build the `sessionFactory`. So, you do not need the `transactionManager` bean.

Therefore remove this part from your `DBConfiguration`:

```
@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```