# How to completely replace persistence in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, hibernate-ogm

Most amount of information found was in the official [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html).

I want to replace the JPA provider completely (use Hibernate OGM)

One solution would be to create a bean for transactions and a bean with emf.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "id_from_persistence.xml");
```

But what I am really looking for is to completely integrate another JPA provider into SpringBoot, how possible is that?

```
@Bean
public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("id_from_persistence.xml");
    return factoryBean;
}
```

If it is - i am definitely missing something out, first exception is Entity Manager is not initialized.

As far as I have understood Id need to provide my own implementation of org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter? As an example there exists the following class:

```
 org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.impl.OgmEntityManagerFactory implements HibernateEntityManagerFactory
```

1. What auto configuration classes to disable?
2. What manual configuration is further required?

Leading on I got the following class suggested for controlling the persistence in Spring:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
```

Comment: It is not Spring Data JPA, it is plain JPA

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: @Herr It might be just the wrong way how I understand Jpa and spring boot, my goal is to use SpringBoot with Hibernate OGM

Comment: Did you have a look at this project? https://github.com/rizvn/HibernateOgmDemo

Comment: @HerrDerb Thank you for this example, it seems to be the solution for me, but unfortunately it fails with the following class not found: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionFactory, How should I configure this project?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464428/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-hibernate-engine-transaction-spi-transacti

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160489/discussion-between-bato-bair-tsyrenov-and-herr-derb).